# How to Convert HTML div tag to pdf with CSS styles with php and Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, pdf

I am Developing Inventory Management System. I have developed current stock report using html css jquery php and mysql. Now i want to add button to convert this report to its pdf version. Report Developed in "tag. Css used to decorate this report and data retrieve from database. Can you help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to this. You can use phantomjs library to convert to pdf. It supports css.

http://culttt.com/2015/10/26/generating-pdfs-from-html-and-phantomjs/